# move text three before the input tag the checkbox is not disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

- if I move text three before the input tag the checkbox is not disappearing when I click the third time.
- but when I keep text three after input tag it works fine.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w6tqvn?file=app/app.component.html

```
<label [ngClass]="{'is-multiple-of-3':multipleOf3}">
    <span  id="redSquare"></span>
three
<input type="checkbox" name="rememberLogin" id="buttonId"  (click)="open()"> 
</label>
```

Comment: If you want to hide the checkbox maybe should be more useful the *[hidden]* property

Answer (score 1):

It is not like it does not work when you keep text before input box. It is because in first case you are providing class to label while in other you are providing it to span. so just provide [ngClass] to label

```
<label [ngClass]="{'is-multiple-of-4':multipleOf4}">
    <span id="redSquare4"></span>
    <input type="checkbox" id="39" name="DownlinkSource" (click)="downlinkCheckBoxClick()"/> 
     4
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean by disappearing is showing the redSquare,
you should **move span after the text "three"**.

```
<label [ngClass]="{'is-multiple-of-3':multipleOf3}">
    three<span id="redSquare"></span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rememberLogin" id="buttonId"  
    (click)="open()"> 
</label>
```